# Send MultipartFile with additional options

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data

what would be the best way to transfer a file from one server to another ? On one server, the file is stored in the database, you need to pull it out of the database (its bytes, name, type) and send a post request to another server and write it there.

I tried to do it in the form of json (the bytes were translated into base64, but the file turned out to be incorrect).

Need to transfer the file and plus some fields with it. Also, the file may not be one, but an array.

How to implement?

[image: schema]

can you show a complete example